# вопрос по flex box.В чем разница между

Tags: css3, html5

В чем разница между `align-self` и `align-items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align-self` определяется в дочернем элементе, а `align-items` во flex контейнере.

Смысл в том что при фиксированном `align-items` в контейнере, для каждого дочернего элемента можно его переопределить задав свой `align-self`.

[Тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8045/flex-v-css.html) очень доходчивое описание flex. Именно после него сам понял как он работат.

Comment: А для дочернего элемента можно  писать align-items? или обязательно нужно  align-self ?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Если дочерний элемент сам является Flex контейнером, то можно, тогда это будет работать на дочерних уже этого элемента. Но на отображение самого элемента по отношению к своему родителю-контейнеру работать не будет.